# \section header Large capital and small capitals {banking}

Tags: header-footer, moderncv

I'm working in `\moderncvstyle{banking}` and I'm looking to have a `\section{Education}` with the first letter as a large capital and the rest as small capitals. I read many of the previous questions but nothing work for `\moderncvstyle{banking}`. I have copied the code.
Thank you!

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}      
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}


\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{My Name}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\thispagestyle{empty}

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{banking}                            % style options are 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{red}                                
\nopagenumbers{}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                       % if you are not using xelatex ou lualatex, replace by the encoding 
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}


% personal data

\name{My}{Name}
\title{Curriculum Vitae}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{}% optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; the "postcode city" and and "country" arguments can be omitted or provided empty
\phone[mobile]{~()~}                   % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\renewcommand*{\maketitlesymbol}{~~~~~~~~}
\phone[fixed]{~()~~}                    % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted


\quote{"quote,\\
" (some). }                                 % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\maketitle}
  {\\[2.5em]}
  {\\[10pt]} % or whatever: space above the quote
  {}{}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{EDUCATION}
\cventry{year--year}{\textbf{M.Sc, Master}}{Some University}{\normalfont{Some, Some}}{}
{\begin{itemize} 
\item[\textbullet] some
\end{itemize}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: So-called small-caps font shape is not available in the sans-serif family for that font.  If you wanted small-caps, you could use `\section{\rmfamily\scshape Education}`.  However, it would not be sans serif, but roman.

Comment: Is roman small caps a suitable answer for your problem, or do you still seek a sans-serif resolution to the issue?

Comment: You also can change the default sans font to another with smallcaps.

Answer (score 2):

For example can you use font Libertine by calling `\usepackage{libertine}` in your preamble. Then you can use `\section{\scshape Education}` to get the first letter as a large capital and the rest as small capitals ...

With the following MWE

```
\documentclass[%
  11pt,
  a4paper,
  sans
]{moderncv} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{libertine} % <==============================================
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{My Name}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\thispagestyle{empty}

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{banking} 
\moderncvcolor{red}
\nopagenumbers{}


\name{My}{Name}
\title{Curriculum Vitae}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{}
\phone[mobile]{~()~}
%\renewcommand*{\maketitlesymbol}{~~~~~~~~} % error with version 2.0.0
\phone[fixed]{~()~~}

\quote{"quote,\\
" (some). }
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\maketitle}
  {\\[2.5em]}
  {\\[10pt]} % or whatever: space above the quote
  {}{}


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{\scshape Education} % <========================================
\cventry{year--year}{\textbf{M.Sc, Master}}{Some University}{\normalfont{Some, Some}}{}
{\begin{itemize} 
\item[\textbullet] some
\end{itemize}}

\end{document}
```

you get the result:

[image: resulting cv]